# Errors running an rmi test program

Tags: java, rmi

I am trying to run the following two classes, but I get this error.
Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.0.0.2; nested exception is: 
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:340)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(Unknown Source)
    at RegisterWithRMIServer.main(RegisterWithRMIServer.java:9)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:146)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
    ... 5 more




import java.rmi.registry.*; 

public class RegisterWithRMIServer { 
    /** Main method */ 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
      try { 
        StudentServerInterface obj =  new StudentServerInterfaceImpl(); 
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(); 
        registry.rebind("StudentServerInterfaceImpl", obj); 
        System.out.println("Student server " + obj +  " registered"); 
     } 
     catch (Exception ex) { 
       ex.printStackTrace(); 
     } 
   } 
 }
```

///////

```
import java.rmi.*; 
import java.rmi.server.*; 
import java.util.*; 

public class StudentServerInterfaceImpl  extends UnicastRemoteObject  
      implements StudentServerInterface { 
    // Stores scores in a map indexed by name 
        private HashMap<String, Double> scores =  
         new HashMap<String, Double>(); 

   public StudentServerInterfaceImpl() throws RemoteException { 
     initializeStudent(); 
   } 

   /** Initialize student information */ 
   protected void initializeStudent() { 
     scores.put("John", new Double(90.5)); 
     scores.put("Michael", new Double(100)); 
     scores.put("Michelle", new Double(98.5)); 
   } 

   /** Implement the findScore method from the  
    *  Student interface */ 
   public double findScore(String name) throws RemoteException { 
     Double d = (Double)scores.get(name); 

     if (d == null) { 
       System.out.println("Student " + name + " is not found "); 
       return -1; 
     } 
     else { 
     System.out.println("Student " + name + "\'s score is " + d.doubleValue()); 
       return d.doubleValue(); 
     } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Have you started the RMI server?

Comment: if you are working on Windows did you start the RMI services from control panel ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you start the registry. Here is a brief link on RMI

[RMI Tutorial (Running RMI programs)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html)

To start the registry on the windows( if your OS is windows) you need to open up the command prompt and type in

> start rmiregistry

else if your OS is Solaris or Linux

> rmiregistry &